# Operating system/hardware used for playing a video during a recorded trial that took place in 2013

Tags: video, operating-system, identify-this-software

I am watching a 2013 murder trial on YouTube  [Jodi Arias Trial : Day 23 : 1 Of 3](https://youtu.be/FRxKpQqfBrE?t=1958).  There is a considerable amount of evidence involving phones and computers.

The following picture briefly appears on-screen on Feb. 26, 2013 during the trial.  Can we say what operating system and/or hardware this was?  Does the ID VTS_01.0001  have any particular significance in computing terms?

[image]

Comment: Cool, but anything from 2013 is most definite off topic here. Beside that, the VTS name has no computer meaning, it's part of a standard DVD structure, and player will show it if no info file is present offering a dedicated Icon and title. VTS_01 simply stands for the first (and maybe only) Video Title Set of this disk. Guess they used a separate disk for each exhibit. And the player hardware may be (most likely) any generic DVD player, after all, what professional lawyer want's to risk presentation of evidence at the mercy computer issues?

Comment: I agree with everything Raffzahn said here. I suggest you try either https://superuser.com/ (for someone who may recognize the screen image) or https://law.stackexchange.com/ (for a lawyer who could say what may have been used typically in courtrooms).

Comment: @Raffzahn - Is there a particular cut-off year for this site? Things move quickly in the computer world.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica See [this answer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11/8911). There's no specific year, it's a bit softer of a definition. To me, this question is definitely not retrocomputing.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica No, there isn't, as that doesn't work at all. Looking back on many cases made there is a general notion that anything that stopped being sold more than 30 years is most likely on-topic, while stuff sold last time less than 15 years ago is usually off-topic. Inbetween lies a grey area where unusual gear may have a better chance being considered on-topic than boring mainstream devices. As mentioned, SE.RC is neither baut capturing fast moving development, nor a support site. Most important for this question: It's most likely not about computers at all.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I agree that "retro" is more about being substantially *different* from current use than about date. A 10 year-old device running Windows Mobile is *much* more retro than a 20 year-old box running Windows XP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your image is of the menu of a DVD Video compilation authored in **Nero Vision**.

[image]

As such it contains no information about the DVD player hardware.

---

I've found multiple screenshots of this 'blue disc' theme associated with Nero Vision in DVD authoring tutorials. However, it's plausible that the same stock image ships with other authoring tools (legally or illegally).
The background image can be seen on various audiobook products worldwide: http://grafamania.net/uploads/posts/2009-07/1248998595_pic_id463658.jpeg which looks to me it might be a Nero Vision automatically-created disc inlay label.

I believe Raffzahn's comment about the name VTS is accurate. The author of this disc almost certainly began a new compilation in Nero Vision, used a default theme, dragged in a single movie file, kept the default names for everything and then burned it to a DVD-R. The end result is a DVD containing the movie file that can be played on a generic player.

Comment: Burning a single video (sniplet) onto a single DVD makes most sense in a trial, as each will be managed as a separate evidence, crunching multiple items on a single DVD would be not helpful in court procedure. And being that single piece, any 'addition' like titles , thumb nails (icons) or menus could be seen as distraction or unlawful addition. So default names and images it is.

Comment: I knew I'd find a source for the background image eventually if I kept searching for 'dvd authoring' 'dvd menu' 'dvd player background'. :D

Comment: Cool, the same keywords didn't turn anything up for me. I had a strong feeling about NERO, but wasn't sure.